# Problema com a codificação de acentos

Tags: java, jsp, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Java Web, e estou com um problema de codificação.

Na minha página já contém as seguintes Tags:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Em seguida coloquei um `alert` no Javascript para dar a saída do `Nome` e `Local`, e a saída veio normal com acento e cedilha (*ç*).
Mas assim que mando o `Nome` e o `Local` para o `servlet` e dou um `system.out.println` ele exibe assim:

```
Nome = ÃºÃºÃº Ã©Ã©Ã© Ã¡Ã¡Ã¡ ligaÃ§Ãµes 
Local = SÃ£o Vicente
```

Segue abaixo código do `servlet`.

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");,
String nomeCompleto = request.getParameter("nome");
String local= request.getParameter("PA");
System.out.println("Nome = "+nomeCompleto+" ## local = "+local);
```

Não sei onde está o problema de codificação, já tentei de tudo.

---

> Como é que você envia esses dados ao servlet? Usa um  do HTML? Ajax? Ou alguma outra coisa? Coloque o código dessa parte na pergunta porque acho que o problema pode estar nela.

Utilizo o Ajax, sou novo em Jsp.
A Função abaixo é a que envia os dados que pedi anteriormente para o Servlet.

```
function sendAddUser(){
var nome = document.getElementById("nomeCompletoTxt").value;
var boxName = document.getElementById("PA");
var PA = boxName.options[boxName.selectedIndex].value;


var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4){
        if(xhr.responseText == 1){
            alert("nome = "+nome+" ## PA = "+PA);
            //window.location.href="#openSuccess";
        }
        else{
            window.location.href="#openError";
        }
    }
}
xhr.open("GET", "usuarioServlet?op=1&nome="+nome+"&PA="+PA);
xhr.send();
```

}

Comment: Como é que você envia esses dados ao servlet? Usa um `<form>` do HTML? Ajax? Ou alguma outra coisa? Coloque o código dessa parte na pergunta porque acho que o problema pode estar nela.

Comment: Já tentou outros `Encodnig`? Tipo **ISO-8859-1**?

Comment: @JoãoMartins Não acho boa ideia. Se o texto tiver emojis, por exemplo, é impossível codificar corretamente com ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Ha, não sabia que poderia ter algo desse género. Sendo assim, não, não pode ser ISO.

Comment: Você está usando o Tomcat?

Comment: @VictorStafusa respondi tua pergunta logo abaixo